# Working with pyspark in Azure Synapse Analytics how do I create a session that multiple notebooks can use

Tags: apache-spark, session, azure-synapse

I'm creating a data pipeline in Azure Synapse.

Basic flow:

grab some CSV files of 837 EDI data. Put those data files on Azure Data Lake (Gen2). Foreach file put data into tabular database table format in Spark DB, named claims. See my flow

[my flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jR4N.png)

My issue: long runtimes. It seems like each file has to create a new Spark session and the overhead is too much (3 min each). I want to "declare" a session via appName and use that throughout. I have 3 test files with 10 rows in one, 2 rows in another, 10 rows in a third. **Total time for 22 rows 12 minutes**.

In my flow you can see the Foreach loops each have 2 activities (one is a notebook, the other a sproc) based on whether the it's an 837i or 837p.

My notebook code:

```
'''python
import re
from pyspark.sql.functions import desc, row_number, monotonically_increasing_id
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# create Spark session with necessary configuration    
spark = (SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName("837App")
    .config("spark.network.timeout", "600s")
    .config("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval", "10s")
    .getOrCreate());

# prepping the variables for the source FileName    
srcPath = "abfss://folder@server.dfs.core.windows.net";
srcFQFN = f"{srcPath}/{srcFilesDirectory}/{srcFileName}";   
dstTableName = "raw_837i";

# read Flat file into a data frame
df = spark.read.load(f"{srcFQFN}", 
    format = 'csv',
    delimiter = f"{srcFileDelimeter}",
    header = True
);

# add autoid    
adf = df.withColumn('AutoID', row_number().over(Window.orderBy(monotonically_increasing_id())));

# clean  up column names    
adf = adf.toDF(*(re.sub(r"[\.\s\(\)\-]+", "_", c) for c in adf.columns));

# now the Spark database side...
# create the destination database if it did not exist
spark.sql(f"CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {sparkDbName}");

# write that dataframe to a Spark table. update mode from overwrite to append if we just want to insert    
adf.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable(f"{sparkDbName}.{dstTableName}");
```

Thanks @Sequinex and @Bendemann

What I've tried:

Added a notebook at the beginning of the pipeline to set the session; see Set 837 env in my flow. The intent is that if a session with that appName doesn't exist it will create it, then use it later. That way I spend the 3 minutes spin up time at the front of the pipeline instead of each file.

```
'''python
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# create Spark session with necessary configuration

spark = (SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName("837App")
    .config("spark.network.timeout", "600s")
    .config("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval", "10s")
    .getOrCreate());

sc = spark.sparkContext;
```

I cannot prove that it's actually using this appName (so if someone could help with that too).

I've tried:

```
'''python
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("837App").getOrCreate()
sc
```

Results:

```
<SparkContext master=yarn appName=Synapse_sparkPrimary_1618935780>'
```

Shouldn't appName=837App?

I've also tried to stop the existing session and start mine

```
'''python
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
sc.stop()
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("837App").getOrCreate()
sc
```

But I get the following errors:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Promise already completed.
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:157)
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.success(Promise.scala:86)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.success(Promise.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.org$apache$spark$deploy$yarn$ApplicationMaster$$sparkContextInitialized(ApplicationMaster.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.sparkContextInitialized(ApplicationMaster.scala:808)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClusterScheduler.postStartHook(YarnClusterScheduler.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:566)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 173, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)

  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 367, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())

  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 136, in __init__
    conf, jsc, profiler_cls)

  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 198, in _do_init
    self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)

  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 306, in _initialize_context
    return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)

  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1525, in __call__
    answer, self._gateway_client, None, self._fqn)

  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)

  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)

py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Promise already completed.
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:157)
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.success(Promise.scala:86)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.success(Promise.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.org$apache$spark$deploy$yarn$ApplicationMaster$$sparkContextInitialized(ApplicationMaster.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.sparkContextInitialized(ApplicationMaster.scala:808)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClusterScheduler.postStartHook(YarnClusterScheduler.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:566)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

TIA

Comment: It's been a year since I posted this. Can anyone help? I had shelved this project but am going to be picking it back up soon.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at Spark 3.2 which is in [preview as at today](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-32-runtime), there are some potential performance improvements there.  However I don't think you can do that type of session management with Synapse Spark, at least as far as I'm aware so you should pull all that code out and get a baseline timing.

Is this the script running inside the For Each activity?  If so I would remove the `CREATE DATABASE` - you don't need to do that for every table right, just do it once upfront.  Also make sure the storage is co-located / same region, fast, not subject to massive concurrent loads etc.  Comment out all the lines from the write, to the clean columns to the row id, backwards and see if you can work out which step is taking the time.

Ultimately Spark is a big data platform so your volumes look a little low for it.  Other options might be, forget about Synapse Pipeline loops and combine into one notebook - see if that's any better.  I have found loops with notebooks inside don't go fast so will keep an eye out.  Also consider `%%configure` [magic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-development-using-notebooks#spark-session-configuration-magic-command) although it would be trial and error.